# FadeOut, effect queue

Tags: jquery, queue, fadein, fadeout, effect

I've run into a small problem regarding the effects queue in jquery.
What im trying to achieve is having an element fade in as the same start point as animation - easy. Problem is when I want to have it fadeOut when animation is ending, seeing as manipulating queue doesnt seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/dpm3x4vw/
**See how box fade in at duration 500 at same time as animation starts.
I'm trying to achieve the reverse of this at the ending of the animation**

```
function animateC(targetElement) {
var targ = targetElement.width();
$(targetElement).fadeIn({queue:false, duration: 500 }, 'linear');
$(targetElement).animate({ left: 0 - targ }, 10000, 'linear');
// I wanna fadeOut in same style as the fadeIn aswell! 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by adding a parent and animating it too. This will make the blue bar start to fade out 500 milliseconds before the motion ends:

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <div id="test">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function animateC(targetElement) {
  var targ = targetElement.width();

  $(targetElement)
    .fadeIn({ queue: false, duration: 500 }, 'linear')
    .animate({ left: 500 - targ }, 10000, 'linear')
    .parent()
    .delay(9500)
    .fadeOut({ duration: 500 }, 'linear');
}
```

You can't actually set up parallel animation queues on a single element. Everything either executes immediately or in sequence, including delays. But there's no reason that you can't animate an element *and* its parent simultaneously.

Comment: Problem is this causes the fadeOut to execute upon .animate conlusion.
As i've stated, the problem at hand is having the fadeout execute at the last 500ms of .animate.

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking It looks like I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer so that it actually achieves the fadeOut behavior you're looking for.